# I cannot use TextField() in jetpack Compose(Material 3)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3, material3

```
@Composable
fun EditNumberField() {
    TextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}){
        
    }
}
```

It says Unresolved reference: TextField.

I want a TextField so that the user can enter a value but it is showing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your dependencies in the `build.gradle` file. You have to add the library:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:$material3_version"
```

Also check your import statements in your class:

```
import androidx.compose.material3
```

If you are using M2 and M3 together avoid this kind of import of both packages together:

```
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.*
```

Comment: Thanks my gradle file was not updated.

Comment: I used import androidx.compose.material3.TextField, updated all the dependencies in the gradle and it worked.

Comment: I have updated to latest version and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the error was resolved for me when I entered experimental annotation like so:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SearchBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            newText -> text = newText
        }
    )
}
```